# iPhone : Display popOver from tabBarItem

Tags: iphone, tabbar, popover

I wonder how I can display a popOver from a tabBarItem ?
Here is how I manage my tabBarController :

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

searchSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
searchRoot = [[[EI_iPad_Home_Root_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
searchDetail = [[[EI_iPad_Home_Detail_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
searchRootNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchRoot]autorelease];
searchDetailNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchDetail] autorelease];
searchSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchRootNav, searchDetailNav, nil];
searchSplitViewController.delegate = searchDetail;

favoritesSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
favoritesRoot = [[[EI_iPad_Favorites_Root_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
favoritesDetail = [[[EI_iPad_Favorites_GeneralDetail_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
favoritesRootNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favoritesRoot]autorelease];
favoritesDetailNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favoritesDetail] autorelease];
favoritesSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:favoritesRootNav, favoritesDetailNav, nil];
favoritesSplitViewController.delegate = favoritesDetail;

agencySplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
agencyRoot = [[[EI_iPad_Agency_Root_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
agencyDetail = [[[EI_iPad_Agency_GeneralDetail_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
agencyRootNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:agencyRoot]autorelease];
agencyDetailNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:agencyDetail] autorelease];
agencySplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:agencyRootNav, agencyDetailNav, nil];
agencySplitViewController.delegate = agencyDetail;

editoSplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
editoRoot = [[[EI_iPad_News_Root_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
editoDetail = [[[EI_iPad_News_Detail_ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
editoRootNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editoRoot]autorelease];
editoDetailNav = [[[EI_Navigation_ViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editoDetail] autorelease];
editoSplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:editoRootNav, editoDetailNav, nil];
editoSplitViewController.delegate = editoDetail;

searchSplitViewController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabBar_search_label",nil);
searchSplitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar_search_icon.png"];

favoritesSplitViewController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabBar_favorite_label",nil);
favoritesSplitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar_favorite_icon.png"];

agencySplitViewController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabBar_agencies_label",nil);
agencySplitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar_agencies_icon.png"];

editoSplitViewController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"TabBar_news_label",nil);
editoSplitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBar_news_icon.png"];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchSplitViewController,favoritesSplitViewController,agencySplitViewController,editoSplitViewController,nil];
[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
```

I want to add a fifth item which will display a popover... any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get my UITabBarItem frame I noticed that on the iPad (on iPhone items are autorisizingWidth it's more simple) items are 75px width and are spaced by 34px.

So I do :

```
(tabBar.frame.size.width-((75*[tabBarController.items count])+(34*[tabBarController.items count]-1)))/2
```

to get the first flexible sapce width.
Then I add :

```
(75*indexOfItemToReach)+(34*(indexOfItemToReach-1))+(75/2)
```

To get the width center of the item.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice against this because that's not the expected behavior for a tab bar. However, you could create a UIPopoverController and display it using presentPopoverFromRect.

```
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:someVC];

[pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100) permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did first but I can't reach the tabBarItem frame. I don't know how to get the right CGRect

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl the tab bar's view hierarchy and look for UIControl subclasses (they may come up in random order, so you'll want to sort them by which one's `center.x` is leftmost). Each one is a tab bar button, which will have a rect.

This approach appears to be within the realm of App Store-safe coding, particularly if you fall back to just using the tab bar's `frame` if an OS upgrade breaks your code.

UIView has a handy undocumented method called `recursiveDescription` that's incredibly useful for debugging. E.g.:

```
(gdb) po [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tabBarController] view] recursiveDescription]
```